# mysql concat on columns name

Tags: mysql, concatenation

hi I'm just starting to learn sql and I wish to combine the columns into one using concat but didn't manage to do it. I can run the code without concat but when when I use concat it gives me an error code. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT CONCAT('A purchase with the purchase ID of' AS "Constraint",
ONLINEPURCHASE.PurchaseID AS "OLID", 'is an online purchase of type' AS "Condition", ONLINEPURCHASE.OnlineType AS "OLType", 'and also a walkin purchase of location' AS "Condition", WALKINPURCHASE.ShopLocation AS "ShopLocation") 
FROM ONLINEPURCHASE JOIN WALKINPURCHASE
    ON ONLINEPURCHASE.PurchaseID = WALKINPURCHASE.PurchaseID
WHERE WALKINPURCHASE.PurchaseID IN (SELECT PurchaseID
        FROM WALKINPURCHASE);
```

But got this error (ERROR 1583 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat')

Comment: I see, sorry I'm quite new to this will work on it thanks.

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in the CONCAT function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on starting to learn SQL, it's super useful! Let me try to clear up your misunderstanding.

The `CONCAT` function takes some number of either strings or column values and joins them together. There's no need to use the `AS` keyword within it.

Here's what I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'A purchase with the purchase ID of',
    ONLINEPURCHASE.PurchaseID,
    'is an online purchase of type',
    ONLINEPURCHASE.OnlineType,
    'and also a walkin purchase of location',
    WALKINPURCHASE.ShopLocation
  ) AS result
FROM ONLINEPURCHASE JOIN WALKINPURCHASE
  ON ONLINEPURCHASE.PurchaseID = WALKINPURCHASE.PurchaseID
WHERE WALKINPURCHASE.PurchaseID IN
  (SELECT PurchaseID FROM WALKINPURCHASE);
```

This will create the sentence you're building in the `CONCAT` statement and return it as a single column of your result set. (I've used the `AS` keyword to rename the column you've built.)

Please let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. I have a better understanding now.